# Where are laravel password salts stored?

Tags: php, laravel, hash, passwords, salt

Laravel uses `bcrypt` to hash passwords.

According to this article, at some point in the process, the `Hash::make` function creates and uses a 22-length random string as a salt to generate the password.

For a single distinct password, `Hash::make` does return unique hashes, hinting that it does use some kind of salting somewhere in the process.

But these salts are not stored in the users table, where I would expect them. How does laravel know the appropriate hash to use to verify the password?

[Laravel Hash Explained](https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The article that you linked seems to contain the answer.
https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/

> The cleverness of this is that the algorithm, salt and cost are
>   embedded into the hash and so can be easily parsed out into 
>   individual components for reconstruction/verification (Please see
>   relevant sections of the php crypt source code at
>   https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt.c#L258).
>   Because of this, you don’t need to store the salt/cost separately in a
>   database table.