# Does Laravel come with all security measures?

Tags: php, laravel, security, content-management-system

I am trying to build a web CMS application using PHP and SQL. I haven't fully learned Laravel yet and I may need more time to complete my course. My question is, does Laravel come in with built-in extra security or is it the same as coding in our PHP. No one told me this, I have a feeling, I would have to do a lot of manual coding to secure my app using pure PHP.

Comment: It comes with extra features and you don't need to build things which are all ready built.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you be a little specific? Laravel seems a little complicated as I don't have any Linux knowledge. I am trying to avoid learning it, but am I losing a lot? I am just trying to compare them as I wasn't sure of right answer.

Comment: Laravel has nothing to do with linux .. yah seems little complicated as first but its more easy to learn laravel than core php

Comment: What comes as stock with Laravel in terms of Security?

Comment: Better go and read the docs from laravel or youtube or some other tutorial .. Its not a tutorial site...

Comment: There is not enough information about security on youtube. Anyways, you could have said that by not being rude. Don't bother yourself answering that now!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a framework does not secure your code magically. You still have to protect it.

you can see your web app as a house with many doors. with pure PHP, you will have to build your doors before using them. On the other side, Laravel (or any framework) comes with built-in doors but if you don't use them, your app will not be secured.

### Example of protections simplified with Laravel

- CSRF protection https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf
- SQL injections using Eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent
- Form validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

All protections listed above can be done with pure PHP but you will have to write a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is several years too late but figured I would add in, locking down your laravel project once in production does not take too much effort. If you utilize @csrf and form validation as stated above that will cover your "doors" there. On top of using something like fail2ban on the server and pointing everything to the public folder within your laravel application will reduce Brute forcing and deter a lot of the common PHP web scans that come in daily from malicious IP addresses. On my servers I typically see certain IP addresses scanning for common php, phpmyadmin, and mysql.php files that do not turn up any 200 http responses. In addition, having the final product/compiled version of the site in it's own directory and implementing all your 3rd party creds within the .env (which is required to link your laravel project to a db) file, make it hard for malicious actors to find system files and credentials.

In addition, the authentication out of the box does all the [hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing) for you "secure Bcrypt and Argon2 hashing". In addition to hashing, it has been noted that the Hash::make function creates and uses a 22-length random string as a salt to generate the password, from question [Where are laravel password salts stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030933/where-are-laravel-password-salts-stored). Which references a Wordpress article on laravel hashing and salting [Laravel Hash::make() explained](https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/). Hopefully that helps anyone reading this.

If you are deploying a laravel site to a VPS or whatever, then I would highly recommend daily or at least every two days coming the access logs and deny ##IP address##; anything that is trying to access URIs they are not suppose to access (since you built it you will know what they should and shouldn't be accessing), and implementing fail2ban to greatly reduce ssh brute force. If anyone needs more info or has more questions about maintaining a laravel website in the wild/linux server, I am always here. Coming from someone in the Cyber Sec industry , that freelances web development